# Is $\neg$Intro necessary for this proof?

Tags: logic, proof-writing, alternative-proof, natural-deduction

Given two axioms from mereology below, I wish to prove that assuming part is a transitive relation then proper part is also transitive. See [(Strict) Proper Parthood](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/mereology/).

The following is a description of the proof below in more detail.

I assume the antecedent $(ProperPart(a,b)  \land   ProperPart(b,c))$ and then try to prove the consequent $ ProperPart(a,c)$.

The proof unfolds the definition of $ProperPart$ in  $(ProperPart(a,b)    \land   ProperPart(b,c))$ and then attempts to prove the unfolded  $ProperPart(a,c)$, which is $Part(a,c)  \land \neg Part(c,a)$.

This proof task requires  the proof $Part(a,c)$ and $\neg Part(c,a)$. On line 13  I used $\implies$-Elem to prove  $Part(a,c)$. On line 19 I used $\neg$Intro to prove $\neg Part(c,a)$.

I used the [Fitch](https://www.gradegrinder.net/Products/lpl-index.html) software to validate the proof.

**Questions**: Is $\neg$Intro *necessary* to prove this theorem? Is there any general advice on when $\neg$Intro  is *necessary*?

[image]

Comment: Note that your proof is intuistionistically valid. What you call proof by contradiction is the standard constructive way of proving a negation. In the context of constructive logic, the phrase "proof by contradiction" is often reserved for concluding $p$ from a derivation that concludes $\bot$ by assuming $\neg p$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note the commentary delivered by your formal proof system at line (19): it calls the rule you are applying "$\neg$ Intro".

And yes, the rule you are applying -- what you are, I think, calling Proof by Contradiction, what is often called Reductio ad Absurdum -- is  *the* canonical way to prove a negated wff in your standard sort of natural deduction system, it is the standard introduction rule.

So it's not as if $\neg$ Intro/RAA is (in general) a short cut or avoidable detour; it's not an added derived rule (like e.g. Disjunctive Syllogism is in some systems). It is baked into the system, and your only option when you want to introduce a negation sign.

Contrast "$\neg$ Intro" with the double negation rule, or equivalently the rule that says "given a proof from $\neg\alpha$ to $\bot$, infer $\alpha$. This rule is not constructively valid; so as Mees de Vries implies, you *do* have a reason to avoid unnecessary applications of *this* rule if you want to keep your proof constructive. But $\neg$ Intro/RAA is constructively in good order -- so use it freely!

Comment: Would it be more correct if I rephrased my question to _"Is  $\neg$-Intro necessary for this proof?"_

Comment: Yes, it would be a better title.  (Also, yes it is.)